# IE7 float makes kind of line break and puts other divs under it

Tags: html, css

hi i had a problem several times while dealing with floats in IE here is an example of what i mean note that this example works in Firefox and Chrome

index.html

```
    <html>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<body>
<div class="some_box">

<div class="upper_red_box"></div>


  <div class="title_bg">
  <div class="title">hi im here </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
div.some_box{
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#f3f3f5;
}
div.upper_red_box{
    width:10px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#ac0061;
    float:right;
}
div.title_bg{
    background-color:#c1c1c1;
    width:600px;
    height:70px;
    margin-left:100px;
}
div.title{
    color:#f3f3f5;
    font-family:impact , Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: So what's your question?  Do not expect the reader to have to deduce your problem by pulling it up in several different browsers.

Comment: the problem is that the upper_red_box div becomes above the title_bg like they are in separate lines

Comment: You should really read this for tips on how to write good questions for SO:  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [a proper `doctype`](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), Explorer will slip into [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Also, you're missing the entire `<head></head>` section where the CSS includes should be inside it.  [See this for the HTML 4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html).

Comment: i really didnt know hat the doctype is such a big deal .. thanks for your help ... :)

Comment: @rainykeys, every little thing that's invalid has the potential to be a big deal... especially for Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to the beginning of your document, and use a proper `<head>..</head>` section around your `<link>` (and add a `<title>`).

Overall, your HTML skills are lacking and so you can't really expect things to work.

But fix those problems and you should have a decent shot.